# is there some way to use if loop in python more than 4 times ?

Tags: python, physics

i am trying to expand my wavefunction is QHO basis and need to define the the following function in python:

```
def basis(i,x):
    if i == 0:
        b=math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))
    if i == 1:
        b=math.sqrt(2)*x*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(hbar**(3/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 2:
        b=math.sqrt(2)*(4*x**2/hbar - 2)*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(4*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 3:
        b= math.sqrt(3)*(8*x**3/hbar**(3/2) - 12*x/math.sqrt(hbar))\
        *math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(12*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 4:
        b= math.sqrt(6)*(16*x**4/hbar**2 - 48*x**2/hbar + 12)*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(48*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 5:
        b= math.sqrt(15)*(32*x**5/hbar**(5/2) - 160*x**3/hbar**(3/2) + 120*x/math.sqrt(hbar))*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(240*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 6:
        b= math.sqrt(5)*(64*x**6/hbar**3 - 480*x**4/hbar**2 + 720*x**2/hbar - 120)*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(480*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 7:
        b= math.sqrt(70)*(128*x**7/hbar**(7/2) - 1344*x**5/hbar**(5/2) + 3360*x**3/hbar**(3/2) - 1680*x/math.sqrt(hbar))*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(6720*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4

    if i == 8:
        b= math.sqrt(70)*(256*x**8/hbar**4 - 3584*x**6/hbar**3 + 13440*x**4/hbar**2 - 13440*x**2/hbar + 1680)*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(26880*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 9:
        b= math.sqrt(35)*(512*x**9/hbar**(9/2) - 9216*x**7/hbar**(7/2) + 48384*x**5/hbar**(5/2) - 80640*x**3/hbar**(3/2) + 30240*x/math.sqrt(hbar))*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(80640*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 10:
        b= math.sqrt(7)*(1024*x**10/hbar**5 - 23040*x**8/hbar**4 + 161280*x**6/hbar**3 - 403200*x**4/hbar**2 + 302400*x**2/hbar - 30240)*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(161280*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    if i == 11:
        b= math.sqrt(154)*(2048*x**11/hbar**(11/2) - 56320*x**9/hbar**(9/2) + 506880*x**7/hbar**(7/2) - 1774080*x**5/hbar**(5/2) + 2217600*x**3/hbar**(3/2) - 665280*x/math.sqrt(hbar))*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(3548160*hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4))

    return(b)
```

I found that i cannot use if more than 4 times. How otherwise should i implement this ?

Comment: You can use `if` more than 4 times. FYI, you have unclosed parentheses in your `if i==7` block.

Comment: But you probably shouldn't; consider using a dictionary mapping `i` to a function that calculates `b` from `x`.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: nah, the limit is 3.

Comment: @c.ried: A `case` statement in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of `if`s you can have, although you should replace all but the first with `elif`s for efficiency's sake. In this case, as [khelwood pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615647/is-there-some-way-to-use-if-loop-in-python-more-than-4-times/29615728?noredirect=1#comment47376595_29615647), the issue in your code is a typo rather than anything else.

However, that isn't a very efficient approach; in Python, a `dict` is the canonical replacement for other languages' `switch`/`case` statements:

```
FUNCS = {
    0: lambda x: math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(hbar**(1/4)*math.pi**(1/4)),
    1: lambda x: math.sqrt(2)*x*math.exp(-x**2/(2*hbar))/(hbar**(3/4)*math.pi**(1/4)),
    ...
}

def basis(i, x):
    return FUNCS[i](x)
```

Comment: you forgot to answer the question, but I like it

Comment: @keyser I just answered *"How otherwise should i implement this ?"* - the actual question makes no sense, as you can have an arbitrary number of `if`s.

Comment: That was kind of my point :p That fact + the syntax error is worth pointing out. Since a comment did that it wasn't needed here.